# Cancellation Token source example

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm doing some asynchronous operations and I would like to use CancellationToken to stop an async task from running if the user for example requests this. In order to do so is it a good practice to have a Dictionary with which I can find the correct Thread in order to stop the correct operation? What I'm currently looking at is the following :

```
    public Dictionary<Thread, CancellationToken> CancellationTokenData;
```

Thus, if the user requests a cancellation on an operation it should behave correctly if I'm not wrong?

What are the best practices to do this?

For example say that the user executes some very lenghty operation on a set {A} inside the database using a Thread {B}. Then he cancels the operation and goes and uses another lengthy operation on set {A} from another thread. Should I use a global variable for the current `CancellationToken` ?

Comment: I can't say I understand what you are asking but cancellations are pretty simple and there's absolutely no reason keep track of threads. You create a CancellationTokenSource and pass its token to any lengthy operation, ie any method that accepts a cancellation token. The client calls the `source` to abort, the source signals the token, any *operation* that monitors this terminates gracefully. It's the operation/method that terminates, not the thread. There's no "current" token, you can pass the same token to multiple operations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok,but are you using a local variable to do this?If I'm using a local one I get too constrained that I can call it only inside the current method, and if I use it as a global variable things can get messy? Should I have one global for each one? I hope we are on the same track.

Comment: Do I understand you right that there are dependencies between the threads? Then of course you MUST use the same Token for them - and using a dictionary makes no sense...

Comment: Does this mean that one cancellation token can map to multiple operations at a single time? @PanagiotisKanavos

No there are no dependancies between the threads Thomas

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Usually, you have one `CancellationTokenSource` per operation that is cancellable. You pass the CancellationTokenSource to everybody who may need to cancel the operation (`cts.Cancel()`), and its `CancellationToken` (`cts.Token`) to everyone who needs to be aware of the cancellation.

At this level of abstraction, you do not stop threads; you stop operations. The threads are merely implementation details.

Therefore, I do not think it's a good idea to map tokens to threads. If tasks are involved, it is a very bad idea, because there is no guarantee that each task actually runs on a new thread.

Comment: Okay, so how do you usually map the cancellationtoken to the operation?

Comment: For example say I want to stop an operation A from executing and I have it's cancellation token with another 10 cancellationTokens from other operations. What is the right approach to link the operation that is executing to the cancellation token?

Comment: @Chris you don't, that's the point. You *pass* it to the method as a parameter. The methods either check it eg after each loop step, or add an event handler to the Cancel event to do whatever they want to do upon cancellation

Comment: To link different operations, you create a new CancellationTokenSource that links to a parent cancellation token with [CreateLinkedTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642252(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How is a parent-child relationship defined in such a situation when the parent doesn't have any relationship with the child tokens? Great info with that last comment and answer ty:)